# name a button javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

well guys i need to know how give a button a name like dont paye attention to the link it's not that necessary:

```
<button class="btn btn-success pull-right" name="next">Suivant</button>
```

here what i did in javascript but i need to add the attribute "name" with value "next" in "q" button

```
    function(a){a.fn.smartWizard=function(m){var c=a.extend({},a.fn.smartWizard.defaults,m),x=arguments;
    return this.each(function(){function C(){var e=b.children("div");
        b.children("ul").addClass("anchor");
        e.addClass("content");
        n=a("<div>Loading</div>").addClass("loader");
        k=a("<div></div>").addClass("actionBar");
        p=a("<div></div>").addClass("stepContainer");
        q=a("<a>"+c.labelNext+"</a>").attr("href","#").addClass("btn btn-default pull-right");
        r=a("<a>"+c.labelPrevious+"</a>").attr("href","#").addClass("btn btn-default pull-left");
s=a("<a>"+c.labelFinish+"</a>").attr("href","#").addClass("btn btn-success pull-right");
c.errorSteps&&0<c.errorSteps.length&&a.each(c.errorSteps,function(a,b){y(b,!0)});
p.append(e);
k.append(n);
b.append(p);
b.append(k);
c.includeFinishButton&&k.append(s);
k.append(q).append(r);
```

Comment: what you actually want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the `attr()` function like you use for defining a `href`:

```
$('#yourButton').attr('name', 'yourName');
```

To create a button on the fly:

```
var btn = $('<button/>').attr('name', 'next').addClass('btn btn-success pull-right');
```

Which results in the following HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-success pull-right" name="next"></button>
```

Comment: Please mark the answer so that other people with the same problem directly see the answer for it